# Hapijs session in routers

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, session-cookies, hapi.js

Is there a way to use session information, that gets loaded with user data from database at the time when a user has successfully logged in, across different routes in Hapijs server routes?

### index.js

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var server = new Hapi.Server();

var routeManager = require('./routes/manager');
server.connection({ host: "localhost", port: 8000 });

server.register(require('hapi-auth-cookie'), function (err) {
    server.auth.strategy('base', 'cookie', {
        password: 'somesecret',
        cookie: 'app-cookie',
        isSecure: false
    });
});

server.route(routeManager.loginRoutes);

server.start(function(){
    console.log('application started running on: '+JSON.stringify(server.info.uri));
});`
```

### manager.js

```
`var users = {
    john: {
        id: 'john',
        password: 'pass',
        name: 'John Doe',
        scope: "admin"
    }
};

var loginRoutes = [
    {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/',
        config: {
            auth: false,
            handler: function homePageHandler(request, reply) {
                return reply('Home Page');
            }
        }
    },
    {
        method: ['GET', 'POST'],
        path: '/login/{user}',
        config: {
            auth: false,
            handler: function(request, reply){
                if(request.params.user === users[request.params.user].id) {
                    request.auth.session.set(users[request.params.user]);
                    console.log("login auth info: "+JSON.stringify(request.auth))
                    reply("Hello, "+users[request.params.user].name);
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        method: ['GET', 'POST'],
        path: '/logout/{user}',
        config: {
            auth: {
                strategy: 'base'
            },
            handler: function(request, reply){
                console.log("logout auth info: "+JSON.stringify(request.auth))
                request.auth.session.clear();
                return reply("You are logged out");
            }
        }
    }
];

exports.loginRoutes = loginRoutes;`
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you use [hapi-auth-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-auth-cookie).

In your app set up you can configure it like this:

```
server.register(require('hapi-auth-cookie'), function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
    server.auth.strategy('session', 'cookie', {
        password: 'aReallyBigSecret',
        cookie: 'sid-ws',
        redirectTo: '/login',
        isSecure: false
    });
});
```

Then in your routes you can configure them to use authentication:

```
method: 'GET',
path: '/aRoute',
handler: function (request, reply) {
    console.log('request.auth.credentials');
},
config: {
    auth: 'session'
}
```

To initially create a session you'll need someway of setting some data to the session:

```
method: 'POST',
path: '/sessions',
handler: function (request, reply) {
    var account = {id: 'userId', username:"hapiUser", accountType:"admin"};
    request.auth.session.set(account);
    return reply(account);
}
```

This is obviously not secure; you'll want to do some sort of look up against a database of some sort to actually authenticate your users.

Comment: Is it possible to set custom values in session. Like {username:"hapiUser", accountType:"admin"} ?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a simple `POST /sessions` option

Comment: I understand this and the part of database lookup. However on trying with similar approach, I found that sessions is not getting filled up with data. Here is an example - {"isAuthenticated":true,"credentials":{"id":"hapi","password":"pass","name":"Hapi User","accountType":"admin"},"artifacts":{"id":"hapi","password":"pass","name":"Hapi User","accountType":"admin"},"session":{},"mode":"try","strategy":"session"}

Comment: have you tried `request.auth.session.set(key, value)`?

Comment: Yes, I tried but with fail. I am not able to set the session value. Can you put a small working snippet here for reference.

Comment: can you edit your question to include your code? Thanks

Comment: You're not setting using the `session.set(key, value)` anywhere. Something like `request.auth.session.set('startTime', new Date())`. You also don't have a route that is secured using this auth strategy.

Comment: Is it not done at login route, I am setting the session there.

Comment: No, you're just setting the whole session object, not a particular key. What happens when you `console.log(request.auth.credentials)` on another route after logging in?